# how to get the window handle and select options on that window?

Tags: powershell

I have Calculator kind of app, i have opened it using its exe file as below. the window is opened for performing the operations. now i need to select an option on that window. how to get the window handle and select the option is my question.

```
Invoke-Item $env:ProgramFiles\tools\App\appui.exe

$Form = Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle -like "*$WindowTitle*"}

Write-Host $Form.MainWindowTitle
```

Can some one help me in this, i don't want to install any UI automation supporting kits.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at WASP (http://wasp.codeplex.com
):

WASP is a PowerShell snapin for Windows Automation tasks like selecting windows and controls and sending mouse and keyboard events. We have automation cmdlets like Select-Window, Select-Control, Send-Keys, Send-Click, Get-WindowPosition, Set-WindowPosition, Set-WindowActive, Remove-Window ... etc.

Or AutoIt (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit) which, imo, is the best GUI automation tool I have used!

Comment: I have already gone through WASP, when i tried to run install.ps1  it in admin and normal mode, it throws error stating that "the file is not digitally signed, the script will not execute on the system" . Any help here please?

Comment: Is your execution policy set to AllSigned?

Comment: Or even Remote-Signed if it was downloaded from the web.